How to use Azure CLI's `az account get-access-token --resource <id>` command to fetch a token for a resource in the list of configured permissions?
After having preauthorized the Azure CLI for an application object (resource), I often use the following command to fetch a token for the preauthorized scopes (e.g. user_impersonation):
az account get-access-token --resource api://779d25c3-6c74-4875-b5ae-ef9b5a04b1e8

This works fine!
But consider the case, where I have configured the resouce with permissions for e.g. MS Graph (User.Read).
In that case, I would like to use Azure CLI to fetch a token for MS Graph using the resource, like I would normally do using the authorization code grant flow, where I would sign-in to the resource and specify a scope of e.g. User.Read, resulting in an access token for MS Graph.
Is that possible?

If you need to specify a different scope, you can use the --scope option followed by the scope you need. For example: az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com --scope User.ReadWrite This will fetch an access token for MS Graph with the User.ReadWrite scope.

Thank you. But this doesn’t let me acquire a token for MS Graph, if the application has a permission for it? Could I use it as follows: az account get-access-token --resource api://<client_id> --scope User.ReadWrite to acquire a token for MS Graph using the application with the specified client ID having a permission for MS Graph?
